# what is being asked here?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I fail to see how this can be achieved:

Define the improper integral (of a non-blocked function) as a limit, and calculate or prove that the integral diverges;

$\large \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{x}}, $

its a definite integral so what's the relation here to improper ones?

Comment: It's an improper integral, because the function is not defined at $0$. It's the standard example of a *convergent* improper integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrated function isn't defined and, in fact, not even bounded in some (right) neighborhood of zero, thus

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\left.\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 2\sqrt x\right|_\epsilon^1=2$$